# filtering an array based on another array based on the order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays one is selectedOption and another is defaultOption, if the selectedOption id is present in any of the defaultOption array option property then it will be replaced with the current one . For an example i have added the expected_output

How could i achieve the expected output

```
let selectedOption = [
    {
        "count": 12,
        "id": "16",
    },
    {
        "count": 3,
        "id": "4",
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "8",
    },
    {
        "count": 4,
        "id": "15",
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "id": "6",
    },
    {
        "count": 34,
        "id": "19",
    }
]

let defaultOption = [
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "16",
        },
        "options": []
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "4",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "4"
            },
            {
                "value": "5"
            },
            {
                "value": "6"
            },
            {
                "value": "7"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "8",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "8"
            },
            {
                "value": "9"
            },
            {
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "value": "11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "12",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "12"
            },
            {
                "value": "13"
            },
            {
                "value": "14"
            },
            {
                "value": "15"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I have tried so far

```
let expected_output = []
selectedOption.forEach(current => {
   isDefaultOptionMatched = defaultOption.find(defOpt => defOpt.options.some(opt => opt.value === current.id))
   if(isDefaultOptionMatched?.options){
      let allMatches = selectedOption.filter(selOpt => {
         defaultOption.some(defOption => defOption.options.find(dop => dop.value === selOpt.id))
      })
    expected_output.push(allMatches[allMatches.length - 1])
   }else{
    expected_output.push(current)
   }
})
```

What I am getting is 6 elements instead of 5, and its not right.

expected output what I am looking

Instead of 6 objects of expected_output array it will be 5 objects because the second last object id => 6 is part of defaultOption[1].options. The element which got removed is.

```
{
  "count": 3,
   "id": "4",
},
```

Which is part of defaultOption[1].options

```
expected_output =  [
        {
            "count": 12,
            "id": "16",
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "8",
        },
        {
            "count": 4,
            "id": "15",
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "6",
        },
        {
           "count": 34,
           "id": "19",
        }
    ]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean with "it will be replaced with the current one"? Why remove only when "id = 4" when there are others that match? The value on "defaultOption[].item_select.value" means something?

Comment: So if you see id 4 and 6 are in selectedOption array but on expected_ouput should only have 6 because its the recent one , Assume if selectedOption had 4,6,7 the in expected_output it will be only 7 which is the recent one of that from defaultOptions[1].options

Comment: So thats why i am trying to get the last one expected_output.push(allMatches[allMatches.length - 1])

Comment: How do you know if one is more recent than another?  Do you mean *greater than* ?

Comment: the last one which got matched so will be getting all the 4,6,7 as matchedArray from that last one expected_output.push(allMatches[allMatches.length - 1]) this is where I am not getting, confused on how to solve this and get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a semi-hacky approach (I don't like bucketing the items and remembering the order to rebuild the array later) but it works

```js
let selectedOption = [
    {
        "count": 12,
        "id": "16",
    },
    {
        "count": 3,
        "id": "4",
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "8",
    },
    {
        "count": 4,
        "id": "15",
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "id": "6",
    },
    {
        "count": 34,
        "id": "19",
    }
];

let defaultOption = [
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "16",
        },
        "options": []
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "4",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "4"
            },
            {
                "value": "5"
            },
            {
                "value": "6"
            },
            {
                "value": "7"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "8",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "8"
            },
            {
                "value": "9"
            },
            {
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "value": "11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "12",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "12"
            },
            {
                "value": "13"
            },
            {
                "value": "14"
            },
            {
                "value": "15"
            }
        ]
    }
];

const result = 
  selectedOption.reduce((acc, el, order) => {
    // bucket each element based on where it's found in defaultOption
    const def = defaultOption.find(el2 => el2.options.some(el3 => el3.value === el.id));
    if (def) {
      const defId = def.item_select.value;
      acc[defId] = {...el, order};
    } else {
      acc[el.id] = {...el, order};
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
// fix the order and remove the order field
const finish = Object.values(result).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map(({order, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(finish);
```

Comment: Seems lot of things to learn from this, let me check this to understand and will let you know, thanks for the help :) james

Answer (score 0):

```js
let selectedOption = [
    {
        "count": 12,
        "id": "16",
    },
    {
        "count": 3,
        "id": "4",
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "8",
    },
    {
        "count": 4,
        "id": "15",
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "id": "6",
    },
    {
        "count": 34,
        "id": "19",
    }
]

let defaultOption = [
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "16",
        },
        "options": []
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "4",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "4"
            },
            {
                "value": "5"
            },
            {
                "value": "6"
            },
            {
                "value": "7"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "8",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "8"
            },
            {
                "value": "9"
            },
            {
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "value": "11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_select": {
            "value": "12",
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "value": "12"
            },
            {
                "value": "13"
            },
            {
                "value": "14"
            },
            {
                "value": "15"
            }
        ]
    }
]

let expected_output = []
defaultOption.forEach(defOption => {
  let allMatches = selectedOption.filter(selOpt => defOption.options.find(dop => dop.value === selOpt.id))
  if(allMatches.length > 0){
    expected_output.push(allMatches[allMatches.length - 1])
  }
})

selectedOption.forEach(selOpt => {
  let isDefaultOptionMatched = defaultOption.find(defOpt => defOpt.options.some(opt => opt.value === selOpt.id))
  if(!isDefaultOptionMatched){
    expected_output.push(selOpt)
  }
})

console.log(expected_output)
```